# Setting #element_validate in a form (not form alter) removes original #element validation

Tags: forms

I have an element with set #element_validate (in hook_element_info) and I use this element in a custom form. The problem is that when I try to add an additional #element_validate to the element in the form it overrides the original validate callback (the one set in hook_element_info).

So my question is, is there any way how to add an additional #element_validate in a custom form without having to use form_alter?

hook_element_info:

```
'ELEMENT_NAME' => array(
  '#input' => TRUE,
  '#tree' => TRUE,
  '#process' => array(..),
  '#element_validate' => array('original_validate'),
),
```

form:

```
$form['TST'] = array(
  '#type' => 'ELEMENT_NAME',
  ...
);
$form['TST']['#element_validate'][] = 'new_validate';
```

And then only new_validate is present when on 'process' callback of the element (as well as when the form is build). When I don't set the 'new_validate' the 'original_validate' is still present on 'process'.

Other elements (tried a few date ones) seem to behave the same way. E.g. #element_validate added in form declaration overrides the own element's one defined in hook_element_info.

Answer (score 1):

You can create validate callback for the entire form and validate the element in that callback.`$form['#validate'][] = 'new_validate';` 

Also separate validate callbacks can be attached to 'submit' ('preview', 'cancel' etc) buttons within the form. And the element can be validated there as well.

`$form['submit_button']['#validate'][] = 'new_validate';`